# Change file permission in C manually

Tags: c, unix, chmod

Rather than using [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-Permissions.html) or any other C library I want to implement my own chmod in C to change the file permission by code solely to learn what happens in the back-end when change the file permission. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

> ...  I want to implement my own chmod in C  ... to learn what happens in the back-end ...

The C library encapsulates the system dependent parts of these functions.

If you want to know what is going on inside the C-library and beyond, you need to how your particular system is calling the kernel - for Linux x86, this is for example the `INT 0x80` instruction. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call to get started.

To learn how each of the C functions is working internally, I suggest that you fetch the GNU C library sources and study them: See http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git

Comment: thankyou! Indeed it is going to help! :)

Comment: @sadaf2605 Good :-) Actually your question is quite open to be answered more concretely, but if you google for some of the keywords from my answer (like system call), you should get tons of material to go through ;)

Comment: Yes, @Andreas, I was also looking for keywords :)

Answer (score 3):

Libc provides you with a cpu architecture independent way of doing system calls. What `chmod` or any other syscall does is move your function call arguments to the right registers or the right place on the stack plus a special value saying which system call is being called (for chmod on Linux this happens to be 90, MacOS - 15) and then use whatever instruction or sequence of instructions that are needed to make the kernel take over and execute the syscall. When the kernel returns back to userland, it has a way to pass back an error to the user. If the error wasn't 0, the libc syscall wrapper puts it into the global `errno` variable and returns indicating an error. On most syscalls the error return is -1, so that the libc programmer can be lazy and use the same wrapper for all syscalls instead of writing a specific one for each syscall (this is usually done through some kind of assembler generating macro or script).

If you want to dig deeper inside the kernel, it gets more complicated. The CPU, when seeing the syscall instruction, sets its context into kernel mode which includes changing the stack pointer and a bunch of other registers, and jumps to the previously set up code for handling syscalls (this is both cpu architecture and OS dependent). It usually starts with a generic syscall handler that checks if the syscall number is valid, moves the arguments from whatever place the cpu thought it would be nice to have them in into a place where the kernel thinks they should be and then looks up the function to call to handle this particular syscall and calls it. When that function returns it usually returns an error code for the generic syscall handler to translate back to the user.

Deeper down. The particular function that implements the chmod system call first checks the arguments (that the mode is sane) and then does two things. First it calls a very complex function that translates the file name into an internal object that represents the file we're interested in (or rather, and object that's associated with the name of the file since chmod is a name-level operation and not a file level operation, long story). That object is called something different in different operating systems, common names are "inode" or "vnode". That object has some kind of structure attached to it with function pointers to lots of different operations that can be made on that object. This is done so that the kernel can support lots of different file systems. It's an object oriented approach. One of those functions is called `setattr` (even though operating systems are free to name things the way they want, setattr is commonly used because everyone steals from each other, also, the operation in NFS is called SETATTR). The chmod syscall function sets up arguments for setattr to tell it to change the permissions on the file calls the filesystem specific `setattr`, takes care of the error return and passes it back to the generic syscall handler.

(I could go deeper down into how the translation between a file name and a node object is done, but I won't. This topic is complex enough to fill a book.)

Deeper down. The filesystem specific `setattr` usually just changes an in-memory copy of the filesystem object from disk, marks it as dirty and puts it in a queue to be written out to disk later. If your filesystem enforces some kind of synchronous mode for attribute changes (this makes filesystems very, very slow), you poke the disk writer to write out your modified object to disk as soon as possible and wait for it to finish. Usually though, you just hope that whatever is writing to the disk will come around at some point and get your modified permissions written out. This is why you can lose filesystem changes when the system crashes or loses power. Notice that it doesn't matter if things got written out to disk or not since everyone who uses the filesystem is working through the same kernel and the same functions and the same in-memory copies of filesystem objects. This concludes the work of `setattr` which then returns an error code back to the `chmod` syscall handler.

Comment: I can go into how the data goes to disk, but I doubt anyone will read all that babbling.